# A reliable and free way to use Linux on Windows, multiprocessor and x86_64

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization

I need a reliable and free virtual machine to run Linux on Windows, multiprocessor and x86_64. I need a good environment to compile and run ffmpeg and libvpx. I have used Mint Debian under Virtual Box, however it has problems after kernel updates. The guest additions doesn't work any more.

Any idea? Is there a special distribution or other free and quite good virtual machine with near native performance?

Edit:
Windows 7 Professional SP 1 x86_64 (NT 6.1.7601)

Comment: VirtualBox is a good solution. If you had it working, and it was good enough, why don't you try and fix your install rather than fish for something else?

Comment: Which Windows version?

Comment: There isn't a distribution that's specifically well-suited or badly suited to running in a VM. Pick whatever distribution you like.

Comment: @Mat It works somehow. I only don't have screen autofit and native file sheering. Cifs works.

Answer (score 5):

How about [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)? Works great for me, though I use it the other way around (Linux host, Windows in the VM).  Within the VM, Windows recognize both cores so I assume it can use them both.

Comment: I do use VirtualBox. Unfortunately the Windows has to be primary OS.

Comment: Vb does work on windows, right? So what's wrong with it?

Comment: VB guest additions doesn't work on my Linux.

Comment: [Guest additions should work under Linux](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11274368), if you've tried installing them and they just aren't working, perhaps you should post another question looking for help getting them to work?

Comment: Why didn't I do this earlier? It looks it works.

Comment: Guest additions, like anything else which includes a kernel module, have to be recompiled every time the kernel is upgraded. Modern software should do this automatically using DKMS or whatever, but sometimes that just doesn't work or isn't supported for a particular distro, in which case you just need to reinstall them (which is what you did).

Answer (score 0):

I've had very good results with a VMWare workstation. 4 years running without any problems.
With VirtualBox on the other hand (XP host, Ubuntu guest) I have a lock up at least once every two weeks.

Comment: VMWare workstation isn't free, VMWare player is though.